# Credit card fee and taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, credit-card, self-employment

On a credit card annual fee: how does it work with taxes? I use that for three purposes:

1. Personal purchases.
2. W2 Expenses.
3. Self employment expenses.

How do I handle that annual fee? #2 would probably fall under my "regular" itemized deduction but #3 goes against Schedule C.

Comment: Is this a business credit card or personal?  Meaning was the card issues to a business or to you? If it is a business card, how much do you use it for personal expenses?  Also what do you mean by "W2 expenses"?

Comment: Credit card annual fees are not deductible on Schedule A.

Answer (score 1):

Credit card fees on a credit card used for personal expenses are not tax deductible. Credit card fees on a business credit card are deductible on schedule C (or whatever form you're using to report business income and expenses).

If you are using the same card for both business and personal ... well, for starters, this is a very bad idea, because it creates exactly the question you're asking. If that's what you're doing, stop, and get separate business and personal cards.

If you have separate business and personal cards -- and use the business card only for legitimate business expenses -- then the answer is easy: You can claim a schedule C deduction for any service charges on the business card, and you cannot claim any deduction for any charges on the personal card.

In general, though, if you have an expense that is partly business and partly personal, you are supposed to figure out what percentage is business, and that is deductible. In an admittedly brief search, I couldn't find anything specifically about credit cards, but I did find this similar idea on the IRS web site:

> Generally, you cannot deduct personal, living, or family expenses. However, if you have an expense for something that is used partly for business and partly for personal purposes, divide the total cost between the business and personal parts. You can deduct the business part.
>
> For example, if you borrow money and use 70% of it for business and the other 30% for a family vacation, you can deduct 70% of the interest as a business expense. The remaining 30% is personal interest and is not deductible. Refer to chapter 4 of Publication 535, Business Expenses, for information on deducting interest and the allocation rules.

(https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/deducting-business-expenses)

So, PROBABLY, you could add up all the charges you made on the card, figure out how much was for business and how much for personal, calculate the business percentage, and then deduct this percentage of the service fees. If the amount involved is not trivial, you might want to talk to an accountant or a lawyer.

Comment: That would need to be one huge annual fee to warrant a consult with a lawyer. But, a +1 for stating that missing business and pleasure is bad news.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The complexity here is that I am not going to use three independent credit cards. Meaning, the point about "business expenses" is only Schedule C - personal income. But that doesn't take into account if I expense something for work and am reimbursed. So 3 separate credit cards doesn't make sense there. Also, it is kind of counterintuitive in the sense that I lose benefits. There is value in putting purchases on one card like that. Also, i can easily identify which is which from software. But how do I handle the reimbursed stuff?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Good point. If we're just talking about an annual fee on a credit card, I think worst I've ever had is $70-something. Tax on that probably isn't worth 15 minutes of a lawyer's time.

Comment: @iq78 The problem with having just one card is: (a) You may have records that identify what's business and what's personal, but if you're ever audited, that will add another level of complexity for the IRS to examine and possibly critique. (b) It creates exactly the kind of problem you're describing here. If I am charged a fee, or get a benefit, how do I determine how much is business and how much is personal? The IRS has a bunch of rules and guidance, but they can't cover every imaginable situation. That's why the IRS routinely says, Keep separate accounts for business and personal.

Comment: How would you "lose benifits"? Does your credit card have some rewards plan where you get higher benefits based on some threshold of spending? If you have a card that gives, say, 1% cash back, then having two cards that each give 1% cash back would end you up in the same place. There are plenty of cards out there that have no annual fees so that needn't be a problem.

Comment: Using a premiere credit card with a large fee such as AMEX Platinum or Chase Reserve has additional benefits such as warranties, price protection, insurances, etc. Obviously most people are not purchasing two of these. On a similar note, what about something like a home router if you work from home? Are you expected to calculate the amount of data used through the router on both work and personal purposes to split it up?

Comment: @iq78 If you want to claim a tax deduction for your home router, yes, you would have to find some reasonable way to calculate the business use percentage: hours used for personal vs business, bytes of bandwidth, something. Given the relatively modest cost of a router, I wouldn't think it was worth the trouble. How many hours are you going to spend keeping records for, what, a $5 tax savings?

Comment: @iq78 Ok, you get some benefit from this card, but it's expensive so you don't want to get two, one for personal and one for business. I guess that would be a reason to go to the trouble of doing the record keeping of separating out personal and business expenses. It's a pain, and if you get audited you'll have to justify it all to the IRS. But clearly their are times when it's worth the trouble. Like people who use a car for both personal and business purposes: the trouble of the record keeping is worth it to avoid buying two cars.